# data-bind for the "dir" attribute (rtl/ltr) of html element

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, durandal

My project is in **durandal**.

I have an html page.
In the page, there is a button, that where the user click on, the language of the table that in this page is changed from English to Hebrew, by special code behind.
Now, I have a problem: I want the **directory of the table's view** to be changed, too.
so I wrote:

```
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-bind="dir:langDir">
    <button data-bind="click:changeLanguage"></a>
```

The code behind is:

```
 var vm = {
    langDir: ko.observable('ltr'),

    activate: function () {

    changeLanguage: function () {           
           //here there is some code of my apllication
            vm.langDir('rtl');
        }

    }        
};
return vm;
```

I have tried to put breakPoint at the changeLanguage function, it arrived to here, implement the code but nothing changed.

Other data-bind code in my page- working wonderful. If I try to change the direction in the HTML code directly (not with binding) it works well. So the problem it just that I don't know how to do data-bind for the `"dir"` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`attr` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) to set any arbitrary attribute with the following syntax:

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-bind="attr: { dir: langDir } ">
```